# Заполнение таблицы с колонкой CLOB из файла на внешнем ресурсе

Tags: xml, oracle, загрузка, clob

В каталог C:\Temp положили XML файл, размером примерно 260КБ и более.
Нужно его забирать средствами БД в колонку `DOC` с типом `CLOB` в таблице `DOCS`.

И после того, как данные XML файла заполнятся в таблицу, то хотелось бы чтобы этот файл удалился.

Подскажите, возможны ли такие действия?

```
create table DOCS (
  DOC CLOB
)
```

Comment: Ворможны. Вы уже задавали [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1218473/217579).

Comment: Прошлый вопрос переадресовали. Задаю более точный вопрос.

Comment: Подскажите,  какие кординальные отличия текущего вопроса и ранее заданного по ссылке выше?

Comment: Какие подробности нужно добавить?

Comment: а) где данные лежат, т.е. каталог C:\Temp на сервере или ПК?  б) почему вы делаете упор на XML файл, какое это имеет отношение к загрузке?  в) что вы понимаете под: _внешнего ресурса_, внешнего относительно чего? г) что вы уже пробовали, и что не получилось (ошибки, нежелательный результат) ?

Comment: а) Сначала для тестов На ПК Windows 7 Pro 32 C:\Temp.Потом На Сервере, Windows 2012R2 C:\TEMP б) Через приложение Java закидывается файл xml (ранее предполагалось  zip, в котором архивированный xml) файл около 260КБ и более, его путь и система: ПК Windows 7 Pro 32; или на Windows 2012R2 C:\TEMP в) Предполагаю что сервер г)Был вопрос, сделать на Java, вопрос удалил, т.к. не было ответов, которые могли решить задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместите файл(ы) в какой-нибудь каталог (в примере: d:\load) и перейдите туда.

Таблица для примера:

```
create table docs (fname varchar2 (128) unique, doc clob)
/
```

Создайте контрольный файл loadxml.ctl:

```
load data 
infile 'loadxml.txt' append
    into table docs
    fields (
        fname char (128),
        doc lobfile (fname) terminated by eof)
```

Создайте список файлов для загрузки:

```
D:\load> dir /b *.xml > loadxml.txt
D:\load> type loadxml.txt
test.xml
```

Запустите SQL*Loader (утилита Oracle клиента) из командной строки:

```
D:\load> sqlldr userid=me/me@dbserver/pdb1 control=loadxml.ctl
```

Если загрузка прошла без ошибок, удалите файл(ы):

```
D:\load> for /f %i in (loadxml.txt) do del %i
```

Напишите .bat файл для последних 3-х команд, если необходима автоматизация.

Результат, как и ожидалось:

```
select fname, length (doc) len, doc 
from docs
/
FNAME                   LEN DOC                                 
---------------- ---------- ------------------------------------
test.xml             307195 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
```

Comment: Создайте контрольный файл loadxml.ctl:
- В D:\load создал файл loadxml.ctl и копирую туда load data …

Создайте список файлов для загрузки:
- В D:\load создал файл к примеру loadxml.txt  или loadxml.xml с содержимым(которое нужно загрузить)

Запустите SQL*Loader (утилита Oracle клиента) из командной строки:
- Если у меня к примеру Username - PET, Database - OL_SR-ORACLE как правильно запустить SQLLoader? Напишите .bat файл для последних 3-х команд, если необходима автоматизация. - Да хотелось бы автоматизацию. Как ее можно сделать?

Comment: userid=PET/password@OL_SR-ORACLE

Comment: _Да хотелось бы автоматизацию. Как ее можно сделать?_. открыть любимый редактор и написать в нём .bat файл. Если не получится, составить минимальный пример и задать новый вопрос.

Comment: _стоит только клиентский oracle. И Sqlldr там не запускается?_, почему не запускается, если sqlldr одна из утилит клиента? Какой клиент стоит?

Comment: Не так написал. На данном сервере будет установлен клиент Oracle тогда и должна запустится sqlldr. Установка будет завтра.

Comment: И в чём тогда вопрос, если устатновят только завтра? Вам удалось протестировать предложенное решение?

Comment: Как собрался тестировать, было обнаружено что Клиент Oracle не установлен. Тестирование будет завтра, без Sqlldr не получится проверить.

Comment: _без Sqlldr не получится проверить_, у вас не установлен на ПК Oracle клиент?

Comment: После запуска команды sqlldr userid=me/me@dbserver/pdb1 control=loadxml.ctl в таблицу docs с копировались данные в столбец fname на несколько полей fname. Например в 1: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?> 2: <IRP_LIST> и т.д. и создался файл loadxml.log с множеством таких ошибок - SQL*Loader-509: System error: Устройство не опознает команду.
SQL*Loader-502: unable to open data file '    <MONTH>2</MONTH>' for field DOC table DOCS
SQL*Loader-554: error opening file.  Нужно чтобы весь текст с xml с копировался в одно поле. В столбце DOC заполнились поля - <CLOB>

Comment: Попробуйте воспроизвести один в один пример из ответа, он рабочий. Пока видно, что попытка открыть файл с именем, которое скорее похоже на содержимое файла для загрузки, а не его имя. Что содержит файл loadxml.txt?

Comment: Да я в loadxml.ctl вместо loadxml.txt написал test.xml. Получается в loadxml.txt если гружу test.zip то в бд в clob идет иероглифами и ноликами. Возможно грузить zip? Подскажите как написать автоматизированный процесс .bat файл, чтобы как только появлялся файл в d:/load, чтобы он его загружал и после загрузки в БД, удалял этот файл?
Можно чтобы читал файлы xml с любым именем, не только с именем test.xml.

Comment: По автоматизации задал новый вопрос.

Comment: Да, по автоматизации, это скорее не ко мне, я не работаю под Windows. _Возможно грузить zip?_, конечно, всё тоже самое, только в колонку BLOB.

Comment: Попробовал с BLOB - в итоге иероглифы и всякие коды подобные  0x...

Comment: А что вы ожидали увидеть в .zip файле? Вам же надо его сначало распаковать. Для этого есть утилиты zip/unzip.

Comment: _По автоматизации задал новый вопрос_, лучше удалите его, его всё равно залкроют. Поместите 3 команды из этого ответа в .bat файл, попробуйте его запустить. И только если не удастся его отладить, тогда задавайте вопрос, с указанием конкретной ошибки.

Comment: Поместил в такой bat файл, но он бесконечно крутится и заполняется clob когда файл именно test.xml    :start

IF EXIST *.xml (

d:
cd load
sqlldr userid=PET/123@O_S-ORACLE control=loadxml.ctl
del d:\load\*.xml

)
echo имя_файла. missing.

goto start

Comment: Трудно судить по неформатированному комментарию, но  goto start и делает вечный цикл. А что вы ожидали?

Comment: Желательно хотелось бы чтобы работал когда появляются нужные файлы.

Comment: Подскажите что нужно написать в loadxml.ctl что он захватывал xml файлы с любым именем?

Comment: Там уже всё написано, он берёт имена файлов в loadxml.txt и пытается их загрузить.

Comment: В loadxml.txt написано только text.xml. Если закинуть в папку load к примеру 123.xml то файл исчезнет и не запишется в БД. Можно как-то сделать чтобы с любым именем записывался в БД, также как с test.xml?

Comment: Смотрите в вашем скрипте. Там должна быть строка, котаорая записвает имена файлов в loadxml.txt. В примере выше это:  `dir /b *.xml > loadxml.txt`.

Comment: Команда dir /b *.xml > loadxml.txt   удаляет текст test.xml в файле loadxml.txt. После того когда в loadxml.txt пусто кидаю xml файл и в БД пусто. Нужно что-то изменить в loadxml.ctl. Код в нем такой load data 
CHARACTERSET CL8MSWIN1251
infile 'loadxml.txt' append
CONCATENATE 4000
    into table docs2
    fields (
        fname char (4000),
        doc lobfile (fname) terminated by eof)

Comment: Порядок перепутан: 1) положить 123.xml в папку 2) dir /b *.xml > loadxml.txt 3) запустить sqlldr. Изменять в loadxml.ctl ничего не нужно.

Comment: Вставил в Батник. Теперь работает. Большое Спасибо.